# Ubuntu bash script spiking CPU usage and not dropping, when run via crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I'm pretty new to bash scripting, but have constructed something that works. It copies new/changed files from a folder on my web server to another directory. This directory is then compressed and the compressed folder is uploaded to my drop box account.

This works perfectly when I run it manually with;

```
sudo run-parts /path/to/bash/scripts
```

I wanted to automate this, so I edited my `crontab` file using `sudo crontab -e` to include the following;

```
0 2 * * * sudo run-parts /path/to/bash/scripts
```

This works, but with one issue. It spikes my CPU usage to 60% and it doesn't drop until I open htop and kill the final process (the script that does the uploading). When it runs the next day, CPU usage spikes to 100% and stays there, because it was still running from the previous day. This issue doesn't occur when manually running the scripts.

Thoughts?

Comment: is your format correct? `*/2 * * * *` to run every 2 min and `0 */2 * * *` to run every 2 hour

Comment: Without the script it'll be hard to say what's the reason.
@qqibrow `0 2 * * *` means at 2 AM which sounds reasonable here.

Comment: There are several scripts running @pawel7318
The first copies any new/changed files to a different folder
The second compressed the folder into .tar.gz
The third uploads to drop box using http://xmodulo.com/access-dropbox-command-line-linux.html

Sorry if this sounds terse, but why would seeing the script matter? The scripts run fine when I manually type 
sudo run-parts /location/of/scripts
But plays up when running the exact same script via crontab?

Do scripts run differently when called from crontab ?

Comment: It may be for example that some depends on environment variables (like `PWD`). I can only guess if I don't see them. You may use [gist](https://gist.github.com/) to share them.